# Very basic question on eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

The eigendecomposition for a matrix $A$ is $A = P^{-1}\Lambda P$ . Suppose $\mathbf{p}_1$ is the first column vector of $P$ and its corresponding eigenvalue is $\lambda_1$, then
$A\mathbf{p}_1=\lambda_1\mathbf{p}_1$.
In other words, we can write this definition for eigendecomposition as

$P^{-1}\Lambda P\mathbf{p}_1=\lambda_1\mathbf{p}_1$

i.e., 
$\Lambda P\mathbf{p}_1=\lambda_1P\mathbf{p}_1$

but how to derive from the LHS ($\Lambda P\mathbf{p}_1$) of the above equation, writing $\Lambda$ as $\Lambda=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2...)$ and using matrix multiplication, to get the RHS?

Comment: I don't understand what is it you want to get.

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado I have edit the question, hope it clarifies.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me. You want to show $\Lambda P \mathbf{p}_1=\lambda_1 P \mathbf{p}_1$ starting from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it should be $AP= P\Lambda$, hence $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ where $P$ consists of the eigenvectors of $A$. 
\begin{align*} Ap_1&=\lambda_1 p_1 \\ \Lambda P^{-1} p_1 &=  \lambda_1 P^{-1} p_1 \\  \end{align*}
Since $P^{-1}P=I$, we have that $P^{-1} p_1 =(1,0,0,...,0)^T$.