# understanding the eigendecomposition in terms of linear transforms

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose the eigendecomposition for the matrix $A$ is $A=P^{-1}\Lambda P$, then the transform $Ax$ of vector ${x}=(x_1,x_2\cdots x_n)^T$ can be performed in three steps:

1. the rotation of the basis to the column vectors $p_k$ of $P$
2. scaling of the rotated basis($p_k$) using the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$
3. rotating back using the matrix $P^{-1}$.

The first and the last step are easy to understand, since $Px=x_1p_1+x_2p_2+\cdots$ and the $P^{-1}$ does the reverse. But the sexond step is hard to figure out. How to arrive at

$\Lambda Px=x_1\lambda_1p_1+x_2\lambda_2p_2+\cdots$ ?

What may be wrong with this derivation?

Comment: “Rotation” is inappropriate in (1). In general, $P$ does not represent a rotation.

Comment: Anyway, you can’t prove the last identity because it’s false. The expression on the right-hand side is equal to $P\Lambda x$. Also, saying that ... $P^{-1}$ does the reverse” is a rather big hand wave. There’s not a neat expansion of that product in terms of the columns of $P$ as you’ve written for $Px$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic idea is fine, but there are some important details that you’re getting wrong: in general $P$ isn’t a rotation. In addition, the reason that you can’t get to $\Lambda Px=x_1\lambda_1p_1+x_2\lambda_2p_2+\cdots$ is that this identity doesn’t hold in general. The right-hand side is actually equal to $P\Lambda x$. You might be running into trouble because of the same mistake that you made in [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580775/very-basic-question-on-eigendecomposition): if the columns of $P$ are meant to be eigenvectors of $A$, then the diagonalization is actually $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$, not the way you’ve got it. The way I remember where the inverses should go is to start from the “bulk” version of the eigenvector equation $AP=P\Lambda$. Right-multiplying both sides by $P^{-1}$ yields $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$.

With that correction, I think that this becomes much easier to understand. Fundamentally, an eigenvector of $A$ gives a direction in which the action of $A$ is particularly simple: it scales/reflects in that direction. Another way of putting this is that a (nonzero) eigenvector of $A$ gives the direction of a line that is mapped to itself by $A$.

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then you can find a set of linearly-independent eigenvectors that span the vector space. These vectors are the edges of a parallelotope—the higher-dimensional analogue of a parallelogram. $A$ then stretches and flips the edges of this paralellotope. In terms of the diagonalization $P\Lambda P^{-1}$, applying $P^{-1}$ transforms this paralellotope into the unit (hyper)cube; $\Lambda$ stretches, flips or even collapses the edges of the cube; and then $P$ applies the inverse mapping that takes the unmodified unit cube back to the original paralellotope.

Algebraically, since the columns of $P$ form a basis of the vector space, we can write $\mathbf x = c_1\mathbf p_1+c_2\mathbf p_2+\cdots$ for some set of scalars $\{c_i\}$. Then $P^{-1}\mathbf x = c_1\mathbf e_1+c_2\mathbf e_2+\cdots$, where the $\mathbf e_1$ are standard basis vectors. Proceeding further, $\Lambda P^{-1}\mathbf x = c_1\lambda_1\mathbf e_1+c_2\lambda_2\mathbf e_2+\cdots$ (verify this!) and finally, $P\Lambda P^{-1} = c_1\lambda_1\mathbf p_1+c_2\lambda_2\mathbf p_2+\cdots$, which is exactly what we get by applying directly $A$ to $c_1\mathbf p_1+c_2\mathbf p_2+\cdots$ and using linearity and the fact that the $\mathbf p_i$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: This really answers my question. It seems the first step of the linear transform (using the inverse of the eigenvector matrix $P^{-1}$ to transform the vector $\mathbf{x}$) can only tranform a vector from the space spanned by the eigenvectors to that of the standard orthonomal basis, but the reverse (from standard orthonomal basis to the eigenvector basis) can not happen, is it? If this is correct, the SVD decomposition $A=U\Sigma V$ also transforms $\mathbf{x}$ from the space spanned by the column vectors of $V^{-1}$ to that of standard basis vectors instead of the reverse, am I right?

Comment: @ecook I wouldn’t put it that way. $P^{-1}P=I$, so $P^{-1}$ maps the columns of $P$ to the standard basis vectors. Hence, $P{^-1}$ maps a linear combination of the columns of $P$ to the same linear combination of the standard basis vectors (as in the last paragraph of theanswer). Recalling the definition of the coordinates of a vector, that means that it converts from coordinates relative to the standard basis to coordinates relative to the basis given by the columns of $P$. Multiplying by $P$ does the opposite: it converts from $P$-coordinates to coordinates relative to the standard basis.